# retrieve only records that has join records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following sql query, which retrieves me joined records. However I want to get places which doesnt have joined records, see below:

```
SELECT `places`.* FROM `places` INNER JOIN `quotes` ON `places`.`id` = `quotes`.`place_id` 
WHERE `quotes`.`user_id` = 1 AND
```

Here comes part I don't know how to write, but I want only to get `places` where `count of quotes = 0` like:

```
"quotes.count == 0"
```

How to add another clause to this sql query, to match my requests?

Answer (score 2):

You want an `outer join`, presumably a `left outer join`:

```
SELECT `places`.*
FROM `places` LEFT JOIN
     `quotes`
     ON `places`.`id` = `quotes`.`place_id` AND
        `quotes`.`user_id` = 1
WHERE quotes.place_id is null;
```

Note that the condition in the `where` clause has been moved to the `on` clause.  When there is no match, the columns from `quotes` are filled with `NULL`s -- which would cause a `where` condition to fail.

Comment: Did you forget the `OUTER` ?

Comment: @Kabulan0lak: you dont need to specify the `OUTER` on a `LEFT JOIN`, because there is no `LEFT INNER JOIN`

Comment: @chresse Oh ! OK I've always written it with `OUTER`. Thanks :)

Comment: @Kabulan0lak . . . You can write it either way (in all databases that I know of except for MS Access).  I used to be quite insistent on using `outer`, but it really is optional.  Now, I tend to mix the two on Stack Overflow but still seem to always use `outer` in real code that I write.

Comment: I've tried this solution, however it returns me wrong records.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Ok thanks. I think I'll keep writing `outer` too but that's something good to know. Have a nice day